# Unable to split a string by "\n"

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I get a list of virtuals machines from my hypervisor and get this kind of string :

> Vmid    Name             File                 Guest OS       Version   Annotation\n1      Win7-1   [VMs] Win7-1/Win7-1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-19              \n2      TestVM   [VMs] TestVM/TestVM.vmx   windows9_64Guest   vmx-19              \n

Now I want to split this string by \n to get a string[] with :

> Vmid    Name             File                 Guest OS       Version   Annotation

> 1      Win7-1   [VMs] Win7-1/Win7-1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-19

> 2      TestVM   [VMs] TestVM/TestVM.vmx   windows9_64Guest   vmx-19

But I can't...

```
client.Connect();

var commandList = client.CreateCommand(@"vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms");

commandList.Execute();                   

string[] resultatList = commandList.Result.Split(new string[] { @"\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

client.Disconnect();
```

This is the content of commandList.Result :
[image: commandlist content]

And the content of resultatList :
[image: resultatlist content]

resultatList is an array with just 1 entry instead of 3...

What's wrong ?

Comment: It seems like the string contains newlines (`"\n"`) and not the literal 2-character string `@"\n"`. Does it work if you use `"\n"` instead of `@"\n"`?

Comment: Spliting with `Environment.NewLine` might help.

Comment: Yes... There is a way to check wich one of them it is ?

Comment: @Helio Unless you're in an environment that uses a different newline character than the input.

Comment: If the debugger shows `\n` then it's a newline (the debugger will show you the equivalent escape code for non-visual characters where it can). If it shows `\\n` then it's "escaping" the slash, indicating that the actual string contains a slash and an `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using @ so the string \n is litteraly a \ and a n.
Your string have new lines not the 2 chars \ and n.

```
string[] resultatList = commandList.Result.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Will split your string.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `@` symbol because the `'\n'` character you are seeing is a newline character.

```
string[] resultatList = commandList.Result.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you want cross-operating system compatability, you should split instead on `Environment.NewLine` because in Windows systems the newline is two characters long `'\r\n'`

Answer (score 0):

\n is a character, not a string

Try this

```
commandList.Result.Split('\n')
```

and notice the '\n' is in single quotes.

Note that since your original string is ending in \n, you're going to get the last item as an empty string in the array.